# Where I can find the Pixel Ratio of the device detail?

Tags: web, screen, pixel-ratio

Where I can find the Pixel ratio for the devices like Sony Xperia XA1, OnePlus 6T and etc. Is there any API or website available or any formula is available to get it?

for ex:

**Apple iPhone 6s**

Actual Resolution: 750 x 1334

CSS Pixel Ratio: ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot and still unable to find any single page solution. So finally arrived the result by opening this website https://www.mydevice.io/ and took the PIXEL RATIO.